# Rate 144.0 Hz not available for this size

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

Running `xrandr` gives the output of:

```
DVI-I-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+  144.0    120.0     99.9  
   1440x900      119.9  
   1280x1024     120.0     75.0     60.0  
   1024x768      120.0     75.0     60.0  
   800x600       120.0     75.0     60.3  
   640x480       120.0     75.0     59.9
```

Thus, it recognizes 144hz here.

However, running `xrandr -s 1920x1080 -r 144` provides the output of `Rate 144.0 Hz not available for this size`?

I recently swapped my Radeon 7950 for GTX 580 and I got this problem. I had 144hz with the Radeon card, no issues.

What changed here? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by typing in the full input. For some reason, this worked. I added the following line to my startup applications:

`xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144.00`

Where you can see the output by just running `xrandr` and choosing your resolution plus desired hz. Remember 144.00, just 144 will not work.